# Get value of DIV - WebDriver (Selenium)

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I want to get the value of div using webdriver and not Selenium
For example :

```
<div class="headerbande">BIENVENUE</div>
```

Is there any method in webdriver to get "BIENVENUE" using class name ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With java you would write:

```
WebElement element = webdriver.findElement(By.className("headerbande"));
```

Take a look at [Introducing the Selenium-WebDriver API by Example](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example) for examples in other languages.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Volkerk, I found the solution via your post

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("headerband"));
webElement.getText();
```

Comment: For the benefit of c# peeps it's webElement.Text -- (property, not method)

Answer (score 3):

in ruby, you can locate the element using

1. css selector

   ```
   web_element = driver.find_element(css: 'div.headerbande')
   ```
2. class

   ```
   web_element = driver.find_element(class: 'headerbande')
   ```
3. id

   ```
   # if your element's id is 'headerbande'
   web_element = driver.find_element(id: 'headerbande')
   ```

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to get value/text by using xpath as below:

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='headerbande']"));
webElement.getText();
```

OR,
You can get text/value by using css Selector as below:

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.headerbande"));
webElement.getText();
```

Comment: In this case, driver.findElement(By.className("headerbande")).getText(); is the better

Answer (score 0):

you can use:
driver.findElementByClassName("headerbande").getText();